# Поменять местами слова используя регулярные выражения

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения, строки, текст

Например, есть входная строка: alex sam, то на выходе должно получиться: sam alex

```
 string s = "alex sam";

 string res = Regex.Replace(s, @"([a-z]+)\s+([a-z]+)", "\\2 \\1");

 MessageBox.Show(res);
```

Но так слова не меняются местами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В регексах захваченные группы обычно используются через `$` откуда у вас `\\` появилось? Вот так, например:

```
 string res = Regex.Replace(s, @"([a-z]+)\s+([a-z]+)", "$2 $1");
```